# how to reuse modal window in HOC in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, high-order-component

I have a modal window that opens if the user pressed the button twice. But I want to use it in another component, so I want to make it reusable. The modal use states from Redux ('randomActivity' that is data and 'repeatedActivity' that is boolean). So, I'm confused by code refactoring.

It's initial code

```
class RepeatedModal extends Component {
  closeRepeatedToast = () => {
    this.props.closeRepeatedToast(false);
  };

  render() {
    const { repeatedActivity, randomActivity, classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
          className={classes.modal}
          open={repeatedActivity}
          onClose={this.closeRepeatedToast}
          closeAfterTransition
          BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
          BackdropProps={{
            timeout: 500,
          }}
        >
          <Fade in={repeatedActivity}>
            <div className={classes.modalPaper}>
              <h2 id="transition-modal-title">
                "{randomActivity.activity}" was already saved
              </h2>
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalComponent(
  withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(RepeatedModal)
);
```

This is code after refactoring.

```
const RepeatedModal = ({data}) => ((
  <div>
          <Modal
             aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
             className={classes.modal}
             open={repeatedActivity}
             onClose={this.closeRepeatedToast}
             closeAfterTransition
             BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
             BackdropProps={{
               timeout: 500,
             }}
           >
             <Fade in={repeatedActivity}>
               <div className={classes.modalPaper}>
                 <h2 id="transition-modal-title">
                   "{randomActivity.activity}" was already saved
                 </h2>
               </div>
             </Fade>
           </Modal>
         </div>
))
export default ModalComponent(
  withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(RepeatedModal)
);
```

and hoc

```
const ModalComponent = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends Component {
    closeRepeatedToast = () => {
      this.props.closeRepeatedToast(this.data);
    };

    render() {
      

      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} data={this.state.data} />;
    }
  };
};

export default ModalComponent;
```

Comment: So you've created a Higher Order Component. Is there a question or issue? Your HOC appears to be missing `state.data` and doesn't use `closeRepeatedToast` callback.

Comment: it is not clear what goal do you pursue. tell more about an outer interface(props) that you need to implement for this, such callbacks or default values etc. if you need to reuse whole modal - so why just not use it as a Component(no need to use HOC), if you need to reuse functionality separately - so write it inside custom react hook and apply to any interface.

Comment: Drew Reese, you are right. I can not understand how to use closeRepeatedToast callback and data .